# Custom taxonomy in WP_Query not working

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy

I'm truly stumped here.
I have a specific taxonomy for sorting posts into different types of "featured" posts on a news site. Here's the problem: When querying by them the results aren't what they should be. Here's what I have:

```
$featured_loop = new WP_Query( array( 'featured' => 'home-featured', 'posts_per_page' => '1') );
if ( have_posts() ):
        while ( $featured_loop->have_posts() ) : $featured_loop->the_post();
            the_post();
```

There is then another underneath, with different formatting:

```
$featured_loop_2 = new WP_Query( array( 'featured' => 'home-featured', 'posts_per_page' => '3', 'offset' => '1') );
if ( have_posts() ):
        while ( $featured_loop->have_posts() ) : $featured_loop->the_post();
            the_post();
```

The problem is, it is outputting posts that aren't in the taxonomy... although which ones it outputs changes as I tweak it, which I find even more strange. I tried a tax_query, and that didn't seem to solve it either. Any ideas?

I used "Ultimate Taxonomy Manager" to create the taxonomy.

Comment: Do you use those queries on same page? or is there any other queries like WordPress's default loop?

Comment: They're both on the same page, yessir. The loop isn't in there, yet. Each is showing 1 post (the second should show 3) and they're just the two latest, not from the 'featured' taxonomy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a silly mistake, of course. 
If you look closely you see `$featured_loop->the_post();
            the_post();` . Which means that `the_post();` was repeated, accidentally. Glad that's fixed!

Comment: Did this resolve your issue though? You don't seem to be querying for any taxonomies?

Comment: I believe it did. I was querying for the posts in `home-featured` term of the `featured` taxonomy. There were other mistakes that I uncovered as I went along, although I don't think that there were any related to the featured-stories functionality.

Comment: Great. I'm surprised that's working without a tax_query, but I guess if it works it works. Please accept your own answer (the green check mark) to indicate that you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using multiple queries on same page, you should always use [`wp_reset_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query), place it after loops.